# Why doesn't this string append with a for loop work?

Tags: python, list, for-loop, if-statement

I want to make a for loop that checks if list d has elements from list ident and if they don't, I want to add them. When I run this code part by part it works, but I suspect my False statement is not working, because it just doesn't append.

```
import pandas as pd
ident=['bla','me','you']
d=['bla']
for x in range(len(ident)):
    if ident[x] in d == False:
        d.append(ident[x])
```

Here is how I want the output to be:

```
d=['bla','me','you']
```

Comment: You want `if ident[x] not in d`

Comment: I want to check (ident[x] in d) == False, yeah it is a parentesis problem :I

Comment: Where is Vallentin? you had commented and actually opened my eyes to it, thanks dude!

Comment: `ident[x] in d == False` means `(ident[x] in d) and (d==False)`. Operator chaining.

Answer (score 0):

There might be a duplicate for this that I can't find, but just to explain the problem:

Python comparison operators [chain](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/expressions.html#comparisons). That is why you can write `1 < 2 < 3 < 4` in Python and it will evaluate as `(1 < 2) and (2 < 3) and (3 < 4)`.

By the same mechanism, when you write

```
if ident[x] in d == False:
```

it is broadly equivalent to

```
if (ident[x] in d) and (d == False):
```

Most of the time if you're tempted to write `== False` or `== True`, there's probably a better way to express the condition.

In this case, it should be:

```
if ident[x] not in d:
```

Answer (score 0):

I understand that you didn't ask that. But let me try to optimize your code a bit. Because these two lists could have equal length and the search could be very long - up to O(n^2). So here are my small improvements that will allow you to make the full algorithm in O(n) time + fixing your error.

```
ident=['bla','me','you']
new_ident = dict(zip(ident, ident))
d=['bla']
for i in d:
    if i not in new_ident: new_ident[i] = True
ident = new_ident.keys()
```

Answer (score 0):

This should produce the expected output.

```html
for x in range(len(ident)):
    if ident[x] not in d:
        d.append(ident[x])
```

Answer (score 0):

```
merge = d + list(set(ident) - set(d)) + list(set(d) - set(ident))
```

it is different way